# Error - "Expected End Function"

Tags: vba, excel

I already have research and find some questions and answers similar, but I don't understand and still can't fix my problem. I have the next code:

```
Sub Keep_Highest_BC() 

    Debug.Print Time
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim d As Long, dHIGHs As Object, dDUPEs As Object
    Dim v As Long, vTMPs() As Variant, iCOLs As Long, Tam As Long

    'On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    Set dHIGHs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dDUPEs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        iCOLs = .Columns(15).Column
        With .Cells(2, 1).Resize(.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 1, iCOLs) 
            vTMPs = .Value2
        End With
    End With

    For v = LBound(vTMPs, 1) To UBound(vTMPs, 1)
        If vTMPs(v, 11) = "In exploration" Then
            dHIGHs.Add Key:=vTMPs(v, 5), Item:=joinAtoAQ(vTMPs, v) 
        Else
            dDUPEs.Add Key:=vTMPs(v, 5) & v, Item:=joinAtoAQ(vTMPs, v)                                      
        End If
    Next v

    With Worksheets("Sheet1") 
        With .Cells(2, 1).Resize(.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 1, iCOLs)
            .ClearContents
            With .Resize(dHIGHs.Count, iCOLs)
                .Value = transposeSplitLargeItemArray(dHIGHs.items)
            End With
        End With
    End With

bm_Safe_Exit:
    dHIGHs.RemoveAll: Set dHIGHs = Nothing
    dDUPEs.RemoveAll: Set dDUPEs = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Debug.Print Time
End Sub

Function joinAtoAQ(vTMP As Variant, ndx As Long)
    Dim sTMP As String, v As Long

    For v = LBound(vTMP, 2) To UBound(vTMP, 2)
        sTMP = sTMP & vTMP(ndx, v) & ChrW(8203)
    Next v
    joinAtoAQ = Left$(sTMP, Len(sTMP) - 1)
End Function

Function transposeSplitLargeItemArray(vITMs As Variant) 'Error is in this function

    Dim v As Long, w As Long, vTMPs As Variant, vITM As Variant

    ReDim vTMPs(LBound(vITMs) To UBound(vITMs), LBound(vITMs) To UBound(Split(vITMs(LBound(vITMs)), ChrW(8203))))
    For v = LBound(vITMs) To UBound(vITMs)
        vITM = Split(vITMs(v), ChrW(8203))
        For w = LBound(vITM) To UBound(vITM)
            vTMPs(v, w) = vITM(w)
        Next w                                ' Error point in this line
    Next v

End Function
```

And when it came to the "function transposeSplitLargeItemArray" it said "Expected end function".

How could I resolve this and why the error?

Comment: transposeSplitLargeItemArray = some_return_value?

Comment: That's usually a compile error. Are you sure you've copied your code correctly? Because this code compiles for me without raising any exception.

Comment: Usually this means you have an `End Sub` where you should have an `End Function`, or that you simply omitted the `End Function` (by mistake). Neither of those appear to be the case here.

Comment: @DavidZemens Yes, I copied the code correctly, and stil give me the error

Comment: check the dhighs.count value?

Comment: @GSazheniuk But I use transposeSplitLargeItemArray in other codes in the same way they are here and it works well

Comment: @newjenn dhighs.count value is correct.

Comment: Whell @GSazheniuk is right. Is the problem on copied codes from one side to another, accidently I didn't copied the last line. Sorry for the trouble, and thanks for the help. Still have problems with the code but this one is solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the soluction for this problem

```
Function transposeSplitLargeItemArray(vITMs As Variant)
    Dim v As Long, w As Long, vTMPs As Variant, vITM As Variant

    ReDim vTMPs(LBound(vITMs) To UBound(vITMs), LBound(vITMs) To UBound(Split(vITMs(LBound(vITMs)), ChrW(8203))))
    For v = LBound(vITMs) To UBound(vITMs)
        vITM = Split(vITMs(v), ChrW(8203))
        For w = LBound(vITM) To UBound(vITM)
            vTMPs(v, w) = vITM(w)
        Next w
    Next v

    transposeSplitLargeItemArray = vTMPs
End Function
```

Comment: False alarm, in the first's tests that error doesn't occurred but now sometimes give "Expected end function" other times this "For control variable is already in use". The first error is in next w and second is in the first for of this error.